# Leading components in principal component regression explain little variance, what else can I try?

Tags: r, regression, pca

I am trying to use principal component analysis (PCA) to reduce dimensionality before applying linear regression. The problem is that my first 10 components are so weak (explaining only tiny variances - the 10th component's cumulative is 0.2577). What else could I try to apply the PCA?

Also I understand the whole process is referred to as principal component regression (PCR). Is there a tutorial or example I could learn in Stata/R?

Comment: Do you *need* to use PCR, or is the question about what else you can try instead?

Comment: First point: how many predictors do you have in total? If you have 1000 variables, 25% of variance explained by the first 10 is not that bad. Second point: PCR is just a regular regression where the covariates are the PCs, so you should only read about regression.

Comment: I have to use PCA as the next step is to do the PCR. I guess that I was a bit lost when I saw the first 10 components were so weak and only explained so little variance.

Comment: Antoine, thank you for the suggestion. I would try and see if I could go further and complete the PCR.